# How to save temporary file / .RData file with walk() or walk2()

Tags: r, memory

I have a function wherein I identify new rows between two dataframes, I would like to save these as an .RData for later use in another function in a temp folder within the project directory.

The functions looks like this:

```
fun <- function(df1, df2){

  if(identical(df1, df2)){

    stop("No new updated rows") 

    } else { 
      df_combined <- bind_rows(df1, df2, .id = "group")

      new_rows <-  df_combined %>% filter(group == 2)

      n <-  df_combined %>% filter(group == 2) %>% count

      print(str_c("there are ", n, " new rows"))

    }


}
```

Here is how it works:

```
mt_1 <- mtcars[1:4]
mt_2 <- mtcars[1:10]

> fun(mt_1, mt_2)
[1] "there are 32 new rows"
```

I'm trying to save the `new_rows` object by adding:

```
new_rows %>% walk(~.x %>% saveRDS(file = paste0("/temp/", Sys.Date(), "new_rows.RData")))
```

I can't figure out the `walk()` aspect. Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: What does "I can't figure out the walk() aspect" mean exactly? Also, your `fun` function doesn't seem to return anything so variables created inside that function don't exist outside the function. There is no `new_rows` that exists outside that function. Functions in R should not have "side effects", they should return new values as needed. I'm not sure this relates to `walk` at all.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, are you saying there's no way for me to save the object created within the function called "new_rows"?

Comment: Functions in R should return values explicitly. Normally all variables created in a function disappear after that function ends. At then end of your function you can call `return(new_rows)` and then you can "catch" that value outside the function `new_rows <- fun(mt_1, mt_2)` (note they could be named different things inside and outside the function)

Comment: Okay, I understand, and for the "catching" part, I can see how I can return the new df, which prints it, how do I then save that output? Or does that refer back to the fact that the function is self-contained

Comment: If you run `new_rows <- fun(mt_1, mt_2)` that `<-` assigns the returned value to a new variable. It shouldn't print the new value on assignment.

Comment: Yes, I see, as in, that IS the result. in this case, I'm going to delete this question and re-think about what has to happen for this one. Thanks for your help.